# Teradata Aster ACT grant access to functions and view installed files

Tags: teradata, act, aster

I've created a new database and installed Aster Analytics function packages (foundation, PremiumPath...etc) onto the public schema.

I know the grant function access command:

```
grant execute on function schema.function to user-group;
```

Is there a way to grant a new user execute access to all functions all at once instead of one-by-one?

Also, the user is able to see their executable functions using \dE but cannot see installed files. \dF returns with 0 results. Is there a command to give them access to view all installed files?

Answer (score 0):

If you use role based security scheme, grant `EXECUTE` on the functions to the role. Then when you create the user, assign the user to the role. The `GRANT EXECUTE` command requires the individual object to be specified in Aster. Alternatively, you could grant `EXECUTE` on the functions to `PUBLIC` but this may not be desirable in your production environment.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you happen to know how to address the second question regarding access to view installed files?

Granting execute access on function does not allow the user or the role to view files in \dE. Therefore these users ultimately cannot see installed .txt or other config files used by the functions.

Comment: Not certain on the use of ACT.